# Matlab Plot in loop seeking names of the variables in an array

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I need help. 
I have the variables (matrix) zco, mgo, dco with 10x10 values. So, I have one variable tt={'zco','mgo','dco'}.
I want to do the loop:

```
for i=1:3
plot (tt{i})
hold on
end
```

I want to plot the variables zco,mgo,dco from tt{i}.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes in the cell array declaration, then run your code again.